# NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
login_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

textbox = login_wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search')))
textbox.send_keys("a")

time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

No error in Python console but geckodriver.log:

```
1514074507756   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1514074507763   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:49865
1514074508870   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-profile" "/var/folders/kf/8800phd97vx28vtzdytqk1m80000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.oI7AzEUKweAr"
1514074509913   Marionette  ERROR   Error on starting server: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x804b0036 (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE) [nsIServerSocket.initSpecialConnection]"  nsresult: "0x804b0036 (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/server.js :: MarionetteServer.prototype.start :: line 95"  data: no]
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x804b0036 (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE) [nsIServerSocket.initSpecialConnection]"  nsresult: "0x804b0036 (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/server.js :: MarionetteServer.prototype.start :: line 95"  data: no]
MarionetteServer.prototype.start@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:95:19
MarionetteComponent.prototype.init@jar:file:///Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/omni.ja!/components/marionette.js:217:5
MarionetteComponent.prototype.handle@jar:file:///Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/omni.ja!/components/marionette.js:112:5

2017-12-23 19:15:11.556 plugin-container[42994:4077314] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x9b3b, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-12-23 19:15:11.559 plugin-container[42994:4077314] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x9e03, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look ino the error stack trace, the error says it all :

```
1514074509913   Marionette  ERROR   Error on starting server: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x804b0036 (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE) [nsIServerSocket.initSpecialConnection]"  nsresult: "0x804b0036 (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/server.js :: MarionetteServer.prototype.start :: line 95"  data: no]
```

This essentially means **`Marionette`** is trying to open up a connection on you **`localhost`** i.e. **`127.0.0.1`** through port **`49865`** but the port is currently occupied due to one of the following reasons :

- **`Port 49865`** is currently being used by some other application running out of your **`localhost`**.
- **`Port 49865`** is used by some service running from your **`localhost`**.
- **`Port 49865`** haven't been released by a dangling instance of a `WebDriver` variant e.g. `GeckoDriver`, `ChromeDriver`, `IEDriverServer` or `GhostDriver`.

### Solution :

The solution would be either/all of the following steps :

- Always use **`driver.quit()`** within **`tearDown()`** method of your `Automation Script`.
  If any dangling instance of `WebDriver` variant e.g. `GeckoDriver`, `ChromeDriver`, `IEDriverServer` or `GhostDriver` are present on your system, **Kill** them programatically/manually.
- Ensure that **`Port 49865`** is not used by any other application running out of your **`localhost`**.
- Ensure that **`Port 49865`** is not used by some service running from your **`localhost`**.
- Use **`CCleaner`** tool before and after executing your `Tests` to wipe off the OS chores from your system.
- Take a **`System Reboot`**
- If the issue still persists, `uninstall` **`Mozilla Firefox Browser`** through **`Revo Uninstaller`** and install fresh instance of **`Mozilla Firefox Browser`**

Comment: Man, that's a nightmare for Jenkins. If a test doesn't release ports, even if there's a test failure, you have to ssh into the machine or reboot it.